# Apache Tomcat Error

Tags: tomcat

See the following error to access the `localhost:8080`:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Unknown Source)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.23-gentoo logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.23-gentoo
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Error to access the localhost:8080

Comment: and....? please update your question and include an actual question.

Comment: Okay. Sorry....

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem just now. if your are on windows machine make sure that you added CATALINA_HOME environment variable pointing to your `<tomcatdirectory>\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Error says

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

It seems either some lib files are missing

OR

Servlet class path is entered wrong

Answer (score 0):

For Java-EE project converted to Maven project with [jstl dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2) in `pom.xml`

- right click the project in question
- open Properties
- click on Deployment Assembly
- click Add
- select Java Build Path Entries
- select Maven dependencies